# Calling ros::NodeHandle::subscribe with a topicname constructed by sprintf

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, roscpp, qtcreator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My Topic names are supposed to change, when I use different sensors. Therefor I want my node to subscribe to different topics depending on parameters on the parameter server. I tried to use this in my CPP node:

> char left_camera_topic[50]
> std::string camera_type;
> n.getParam("/neuromorphic_stereo/config/camera_type",
> camera_type);
> sprintf(left_camera_topic,"/%s_left/events",camera_type);
> ros::Subscriber leftCam  =
> n.subscribe(left_camera_topic_string,
> subscriberCallback);

with

> void subscriberCallback(const
> dvs_msgs::EventArray& msg);

But building this gets me the error

> error: no matching function for call
> to 'ros::NodeHandle::subscribe(const
> char [50], void (&)(const
> EventArray&))'    ros::Subscriber
> leftCam  =
> n.subscribe(left_camera_topic_string,
> subscriberCallback);

Is it not possible to construct the topicnames like this, or am I doing something wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308572/calling-ros::nodehandle::subscribe-with-a-topicname-constructed-by-sprintf/) by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2018-11-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-15**:
Why did you delete your question?

**Comment by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on 2018-11-15**:
@gvdhoorn I'm sorry I deleted the question before you posted your answer because I just did a stupid mistake: I forgot the buffer-size argument of the subscribe function. adding that argument makes the code work and your answer therefor doesn't solve the problem.

**Comment by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on 2018-11-15**:
@gvdhoorn I could, of course, reopen the question and you adjust your answer to fit the solution. And thanks for the remapping suggestion, I'll have a look at that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-15**:
I would suggest to re-open the question, and answer your own question. Then accept that answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it not possible to construct the topicnames like this, or am I doing something wrong?

Raw `char` arrays are not `std::string`s, so that's why you get that error.

If you really must use `char`, you could wrap it in a `std::string(..)` ctor.

But I don't understand why you are using `char` in the first place: `std::string` is a type 'natively' supported by the `ros::param` API.

And an observation:

> My Topic names are supposed to change, when I use different sensors. Therefor I want my node to subscribe to different topics depending on parameters on the parameter server.

Unless you are creating and destroying subscriptions at runtime (so have to change these during the entire runtime of your program, not just in the initialisation phase), don't do this. Don't parameterise topic names like this.

I would suggest to use [remapping](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap). See #q303611 for a (very) high-level overview of what that does.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on 2018-11-15**:
The reason for me to use char-arrays instead of strings is that strings don't work as buffer in sprintf (at least I couldn't figure out, how. Kind of new to c++... ;))

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-11-15**:
But with `std::string`, the `+` operator can be used to concatenate strings, so no need for `sprintf(..)` it would seem.

But I would still not use parameters for topic names, as I wrote in my answer.

**Comment by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on 2018-11-19**:
You were right in the end, gvdhoorn. Using the + operator instead of printf worked just fine. Thanks for your help.